# A monopolist has decreasing average costs, setting the price equal to AC will lead to?

Tags: monopoly, monopolistic-competition

1)what will happen to the Output compared to the situation where **MR=MC** ?

2)what will happen to the Output compare to **Competitive Output**?

***Attempt at Soln. :*** 
1)
2) so definitely quantity of o/t for monopoly < quantity of competitive o/t .

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is called a "natural monopoly". Real life examples are of electric and water companies. Natural monopolies should not be split up by anti-trust laws because they are still producing on a part of the ATC curve where they experience economies of scale.